# LDAP get user email

Tags: email, ldap

LDAP

How can I get user email attribute from LDAP server for domain user using bash?

I suppose that I should use ldapsearch command.

I have the following information about ldap server:

Server Name: server.url

Server Port number: portnum

Search base: dc=prefix1,dc=db

Account name: domain\user_name

Password: domain_password

Answer (score 3):

`ldapsearch -h Hostname -p port# -D dc=prefix1,dc=db -b cn=username,cn=User,dc=prefix1,dc=db "sAMAccountName=YourUsersName" mail`

You will need the real DN of the Acount name, which you can search for, using same as above, and get the DN out of the result.

Comment: Unfortuanetly i got an error.   (with real dc and sAMAccountName=domain/usernametofindemail)       # search result
search: 2
result: 1 Operations error
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this ope
 ration a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1